# Rust Diesel - Retrieve parent in association

Tags: rust, rust-diesel

From the Diesel documentation I can see that it is possible to retrieve all the children of a selected parent using the *belonging_to* method:
https://docs.diesel.rs/diesel/associations/index.html

In the example, the first Post of the User is retrieved using *belonging_to*:

```
let user = users.find(2).get_result::<User>(&connection)?;
let users_post = Post::belonging_to(&user)
    .first(&connection)?;
```

I would like to know if Diesel offers the possibility to obtain the parent from the child (in the example, the User from the Post).
It would even better to insert the User in a variable of the Post struct.

Comment: if we already have the foreign key in the instance then why we would need another method to access the parent.

Comment: Hi @Chandan
of course, I could just perform the following query:
`let res = users.find(id).get_result::<User>(conn)`
but then I could say the same thing for the belonging_to method... Of course, in this case we have multiple ids instead of only one, and it manages N+1 query issue, but you still need to extract the ID from the struct and perform the query explicitly... So I was just asking if a method to retrieve a parent based on the association we declared in the code exists or not.